# Cant find required class org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils while building on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, compilation

OS Java8 jdk1.8

When running my build using `mvn clean install -P TestExecutor` on Jenkins I get following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (generate-cucumber-reports) on project testing: Execution generate-cucumber-reports of goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils
```

Locally it's running and just fine. Here is the catch: I don't find the `org/apache/commons/lang3/` in my local m2 repository (I do have the `commons-lang3`) and it does not appear on the `mvn dependency:tree` list.

So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

        <cucumber.version>7.3.3</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.1.4</selenium.version>
        <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
        <assertj.version>3.22.0</assertj.version>
        <commonsmodel.version>5.3.3</commonsmodel.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M6</maven.surefire.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.8.2</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <maven-cucumber-reporting.version>5.7.0</maven-cucumber-reporting.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version </version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>TestExecutor</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
<!--                        <dependencies>-->
<!--                            <dependency>-->
<!--                                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>-->
<!--                                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>-->
<!--                                <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>-->
<!--                            </dependency>-->
<!--                        </dependencies>-->
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <includes>**/ExecutorTest.java</includes>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!--cucumber report plugin-->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-cucumber-reports</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <projectName>Automation report</projectName>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</inputDirectory>
                                    <jsonFiles>
                                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                                    </jsonFiles>
                                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

Edit:
the full error log reads like this

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.662 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-14T17:04:00+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/258M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (generate-cucumber-reports) on project testing: Execution generate-cucumber-reports of goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/net/masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting/5.7.0/maven-cucumber-reporting-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/net/masterthought/cucumber-reporting/5.7.0/cucumber-reporting-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: [This](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0) is the latest Lang 3. Skip [3.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4) (it has vulns)

Comment: hi @g00se I have the latest `commons-lang3` dependency set in my pom. The problem is the lang3, not the commons-lang3

Comment: Can you please share which Maven version you are using? Also which OS you are on And which JDK you are using? Also can you post more of the error output...

Comment: JAVA8 jdk 1.8 and the full error is posted above

Answer (score 1):

If you add the dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.4</version> 
</dependency>
```

does it work? The artifactid should be commons-lang3.
Jenkins just runs the maven build and downloads what's needed.

Comment: hi @Dan Chirita as you can see in my attached pom my dependency is added like that, but only with a newer version. It complains about lang3, not commons-lang3

Comment: Ok, so, as said before, the artifactId is not written correctly: it should be `commons-lang3`, not `lang3`, and if you want the version 3.12.0, your dependency should look like this:`<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>${commons-lang3.version}</version> 
</dependency>`

Comment: so exactly as it says in my pom?

Comment: you can replace your dependency in pom with the one from my comment above. you should, then, get rid of the issue

Comment: thanks for your help, but really my dependency is set like you say it... I'll paste here again:

       `<commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>`
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>`

this is using the 3.12.0 like u mentioned above. And for your og comment I have tried 3.4 as well but same error

Comment: could you, please, add more from the error log?

Comment: Not really sure what more you need from the error log than I added in the mainpost i.e. the whole error log

Answer (score 0):

You are missing commons in artifactId, try using below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Rishi, the commons-lang is set like this.

Answer (score 0):

**artifactId** is wrong in your dependency. Make it like below

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Take reference from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

Comment: hi @Nitika I have the latest `commons-lang3` dependency already set in my pom (see above). I am using the latest version, not the 3.4. The problem is I think the lang3, not the commons-lang3

Comment: @Thomarkey but if you check https://mvnrepository.com, there does not exist any artifactId as lang3 for which groupId is org.apache.commons. so if you add your dependency, it will give you error - could not find artifact.

Comment: @Thomarkey How about deleting the `lang3` dependency as you have already added `commons-lang3` dependency and then build the project ?

Comment: as the error mentions, than it does not find the `org.apache.commons:lang3` artifact. This is a different one than the `org.apache.commons-lang3` no?

Comment: @Thomarkey: yes

Comment: yes, so.. how to fix this?